# Finding subvector of maximum length containing a small proportion of 0's

Tags: r, vector, count

I have a vector that contains a sequence of 1 and 0. Suppose of it is of length 166 and it is

```
  y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

Now I want to to extract a LONGEST POSSIBLE sub vector from above vector such that it satisfies two properties

(1) sub-vector should start from 1 and end with 1.

(2) It can contain up to 5% zeros of total length of sub-vector.

I started with `rle` function. It counts the 1 and 0 at each step.
So it will be like

```
z <- rle(y)
d <- data.frame(z$values, z$lengths)
colnames(d) <- c("value", "length")
```

It gives me

```
> d
   value length
1      1     22
2      0      1
3      1     13
4      0      1
5      1      2
6      0      1
7      1      1
8      0      1
9      1      1
10     0      5
11     1      1
12     0      3
13     1      2
14     0      1
15     1      1
16     0      1
17     1     74
18     0      2
19     1     17
20     0      1
21     1      2
22     0      1
23     1      3
24     0      5
25     1      4
```

In this case 74 + 2+ 17 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 99 is the required sub-sequence as it contains  2+1+1=4 zeros which is less than 5% of 99. If we move forward and sequence will become 99+5+4 =108 and zeros will be 4+5=9 which will be more than 5% of 108.

Comment: I think your subvector is actually of length 100 (74+2+17+1+2+1+3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are very close by computing the run-length encoding of this vector. All that remains is to consider all pairs of runs of 1's and to select the pair that is of the longest length and matches the "no more than 5% zeros" rule. This can be done in a fully vectorized manner using `combn` to compute all pairs of runs of 1's and `cumsum` to get lengths of runs from the `rle` output:

```
ones <- which(d$value == 1)
# pairs holds pairs of rows in d that correspond to runs of 1's
if (length(ones) >= 2) {
  pairs <- rbind(t(combn(ones, 2)), cbind(ones, ones))
} else if (length(ones) == 1) {
  pairs <- cbind(ones, ones)
}

# Taking cumulative sums of the run lengths enables vectorized computation of the lengths
#   of each run in the "pairs" matrix
cs <- cumsum(d$length)
pair.length <- cs[pairs[,2]] - cs[pairs[,1]] + d$length[pairs[,1]]
cs0 <- cumsum(d$length * (d$value == 0))
pair.num0 <- cs0[pairs[,2]] - cs0[pairs[,1]]

# Multiple the length of a pair by an indicator for whether it's valid and take the max
selected <- which.max(pair.length * ((pair.num0 / pair.length) <= 0.05))
d[pairs[selected,1]:pairs[selected,2],]
#    value length
# 15     1      1
# 16     0      1
# 17     1     74
# 18     0      2
# 19     1     17
# 20     0      1
# 21     1      2
# 22     0      1
# 23     1      3
```

We actually found a subvector that is slightly longer that the one found by the OP: it has 102 elements and five 0's (4.90%).

Comment: Thanks josliber, It really helped a lot and yes the correct answer is 102.

Comment: You can do the same with combn: `r = rle(y);
w1 = which(r$values==1);
v = combn(w1, 2, FUN = function(i) with(lapply(r,\`[\`, i[1]:i[2]), {
    sum(lengths) * ( sum(lengths[values==1]) > .95*sum(lengths))
}));
combn(w1,2)[,which.max(v)]`

Comment: @Frank yes, though for very large vectors I should get a significant performance boost from using vectorized operations and not looping through each pair of rows and separately processing them. Also `combn` doesn't give (i, i) pairs (aka the start and end row being the same), which is important if we had a vector where we can never include a 0 in the selected subvector (e.g. `y <- c(1, 0, 1)`).

Comment: Whoops, forgot about (i,i) pairs. For performance, I guess a loop might be best, depending on the data, starting from the pairs furthest away (since, if x:y meets the criterion, it dominates x1:y1 for x1>x, y1<y, so the latter doesn't need to be checked).

Comment: @josliber, there is one exception. I have a vector `y <- c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 134), rep(0, 75))` which gives the result as `value length
1     0    100
2     1    134` which does not give the correct answer. However most of the part works fine. How can we handle this?

Comment: @Pankaj OK, this was caused by issues with the special case where there was only a single run of 1's. I've fixed up the code to handle that special case.